# Grouping elements close together

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I'm trying to figure out a solid way of grouping elements together that a value is next in the list.

The data I have is this

```swift
let values = [
    ChartDataEntry(x: 0.0, y: -13.0),
    ChartDataEntry(x: 1.0, y: -13.0),
    ChartDataEntry(x: 2.0, y: 0.68),
    ChartDataEntry(x: 3.0, y: -13.0),
    ChartDataEntry(x: 4.0, y: 1.7),
    ChartDataEntry(x: 5.0, y: 0.5),
    ChartDataEntry(x: 6.0, y: 10.0)
]
```

I'm trying to group it so it's more like this

```swift
let values = [
    [
        ChartDataEntry(x: 0.0, y: -13.0),
        ChartDataEntry(x: 1.0, y: -13.0),
        ChartDataEntry(x: 3.0, y: -13.0)
    ],
    [
        ChartDataEntry(x: 2.0, y: 0.68)
    ],
    [
        ChartDataEntry(x: 4.0, y: 1.7),
        ChartDataEntry(x: 5.0, y: 0.5),
        ChartDataEntry(x: 6.0, y: -10.0)
    ]
]
```

Essentially the grouping I am trying to achieve is elements that x elements that have a value above -13.0 go together and elements below -13 go together. The tricky part is grouping by the x value.

The goal is to group values by the x value that are next to each other.

x: 2.0 is next to 3.0, but it's -13, so it doesnt belong in the same group, but if you look at 4.0, 5.0, & 6.0, they would all get grouped together as they have a value greater than -13 consecutively

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this is a simple composition of three separate processes. 1) Partition all elements being under or over `-13.0`. 2) Sort both sides by their X values 3) Split apart elements to form runs of consecutive X values. Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: Why -13? Are you trying to group together points in a chart which are very close? In that case -13 would change based on values of other points in chart right? You may have to use some other algorithm to achieve this grouping then. I am afraid it wont be as straight forward as you think if that is the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simple solution I found to achieve this is with with reduce function. If anyone has any other cleaner more concise approaches, I'm all ears.

```swift
let grouped = values.filter({ $0.y != -13 }).reduce([[ChartDataEntry]]()) { result, item in
    var result = result
    if let lastX = result.last?.last?.x, item.x - 1.0 == lastX {
        let lastIndex = result.count - 1
         result[lastIndex].append(item)
    } else {
        result.append([item])
    }
    return result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [reduce(into:_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3126956-reduce) method and enumerate the array elements. If `ChartDataEntry y` value is less than `-13.0`, get the array index where its elements are less than or equal to `-13.0` and append the `ChartDataEntry` object to that sub array. If not find the sub array which contains a `ChartDataEntry` object with `x` value adjacent to current `ChartDataEntry` object, and append to the sub array. If both condition fails append a new sub array with the `ChartDataEntry` object.

```
let result = values.reduce(into: [[ChartDataEntry]]()) { (result, chart) in
    if chart.y <= -13.0, let index = result.firstIndex(where: { $0.contains(where: { $0.y <= -13.0 }) }) {
        result[index].append(chart)
    } else if let index = result.firstIndex(where: { $0.contains(where: { $0.y > -13.0 && $0.x.advanced(by: 1) == chart.x }) }) {
        result[index].append(chart)
    } else {
        result.append([chart])
    }
}
print(result)

//[[ChartDataEntry(x: 0.0, y: -13.0), ChartDataEntry(x: 1.0, y: -13.0), ChartDataEntry(x: 3.0, y: -13.0)],
//[ChartDataEntry(x: 2.0, y: 0.68)],
//[ChartDataEntry(x: 4.0, y: 1.7), ChartDataEntry(x: 5.0, y: 0.5), ChartDataEntry(x: 6.0, y: 10.0)]]
```